# Enable a signal handler using sigaction in C

Tags: c

```
  struct sigaction psa;
```

I have enabled my signal handler in the main function as shown below:

```
    memset (&psa, 0, sizeof (psa));
    psa.sa_handler = pSigHandler;
    sigaction (SIGALRM, &psa, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGVTALRM, &psa, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGPROF, &psa, NULL);
```

My signal handler is like this:

```
static void pSigHandler(int signo){
    printf("Pareint signum: %d", signo);// debug
    switch (signo) {
        case SIGALRM:
            printf("P SIGALRM handler");//debug
            break;
        case SIGVTALRM:
            printf("P SIGVTALRM handler");//debug
            break;
        case SIGPROF:
            printf("P SIGPROF handler");//debug
            break;
        default: /*Should never get this case*/
            break;
    }
    return;
}
```

Now my question may be obvious to some people, why didn't I see the printed debug lines when I run this? In fact, nothing was printed. Thank you very much for helping me to understand this. I'm running it on Linux, used Eclipse to program.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

static void pSigHandler(int signo){
    switch (signo) {
            case SIGTSTP:
            printf("TSTP");
            fflush(stdout);
            break;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    struct sigaction psa;
    psa.sa_handler = pSigHandler;
    sigaction(SIGTSTP, &psa, NULL);
    for(;;) {}
    return 0;
}
```

Because you need to fflush(stdout)

try with C-z

I'm not even sure if it's safe to use stdio in a signal handler though.

Update: http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/440109-signal-handler-sigsegv

According to that link, you should not do this.

Comment: I tried to add in fflush(stdout); still did not print out anything, 
I commented out other codes in my program, so it look pretty much the same as above, just without the infinite loop. Any ideas? Thank you Tom.

Comment: In my code sample, the fflush makes the difference between printing or not. I think maybe the app isn't getting your signals? Have you tried mine? I think this might be undefined behavior anyway, the link I put at the bottom has some info in it that explains that you're only supposed to do certain things in there... It should be in your system's docs.

Comment: You also mention you removed the infinite loop--- If that's not there, the code will exit and the signal handlers will be gone... You need to block and wait for the signals...

Comment: Still did not print anything after adding the loop. I also tried sa_mask, still nothing, not sure if the signal is blocked in anyway?
        struct sigaction psa;
 psa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigemptyset(&psa.sa_mask);
 memset (&psa, 0, sizeof (psa));
 psa.sa_handler = pSigHandler;
 sigaction (SIGALRM, &psa, NULL);
 sigaction(SIGVTALRM, &psa, NULL);
 sigaction(SIGPROF, &psa, NULL);
 signal(SIGALRM, pSigHandler);

 for(;;);//debug

Comment: ah, it finally printed out, it is very weired, I still do not fully understand, but it printed out after I put my remaining codes in, and it seems the printing statement output is not consistent in the handler? Anyway, problem kind of solved. Thank you Tom nonetheless.

Comment: Based on https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html, sa_handler is used only when sa_flags is set to SA_SIGINFO. This program does not set the flag. So its behavior is a bit undefined...

Comment: @JoeC read that man page again, the opposite of that is true