# Use of sigaction()

Tags: c, signals

I have to send two signals to a process, `SIGUSR1` and `SIGUSR2`, in order to modify a particular boolean variable in the program (`SIGUSR1` sets it to *true*, `SIGUSR2` sets it to *false*). So I wrote a `signalHandler()` function in order to control the behavior of `SIGUSR1` or `SIGUSR2`. The problem is: **how to set `sigaction()` to handle this particular task?**  I spent a lot of time on Google, I read everywhere that I should use `sigaction()` instead of the obsolete `signal()`. In the man page i found this

```
int sigaction(int signum, const struct sigaction *act,struct sigaction *oldact);
```

in signum I have to put the type of signal I want to handle, then I have a struct sigaction parameter:

```
  struct sigaction {
       void     (*sa_handler)(int);
       void     (*sa_sigaction)(int, siginfo_t *, void *);
       sigset_t   sa_mask;
       int        sa_flags;
       void     (*sa_restorer)(void);
   };
```

in the first field i thought i should set the name of my signal handler, but I don't know how can I set the other fields.

Finally, what is the use of: `struct sigaction *oldact`?

Comment: `oldact` stores the previous signal handling state for signal number `signum`.

Comment: @moshbear can i set it to NULL if i don't want to use it?

Comment: __ Yes, you can. (pardon the underscores, but there's a 15-char min length limit for comments).

Comment: @moshbear thank you! In this question i see that he just set the .sa_handler parameter of the structure, is it ok?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113545/enable-a-signal-handler-using-sigaction-in-c

Comment: @Sorcipuppolo: You have to zero the rest out at least.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the [sigaction(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigaction) manual page. It's all described there.

Basically you set either `sa_handler` or `sa_sigaction` depending on whether you want the extra signal info.

If you set the later, you need to add `SA_SIGINFO` to the flags. Otherwise the flags should probably be 0 for your case. You probably want system calls to fail with errno `EINTR` when interrupted with the signal (default behaviour), so you can consider the new value of the variable before restarting them, but if you ended up wanting to restart them automatically (`select` and `poll` are never restarted), you can set the `SA_RESTART` flag.

The `sa_mask` is set of signals that should be defered while this singal handler is running. You should set at least the two signals, so they don't get mixed up if they come in quick succession.

And the last, `sa_restorer` is obsolete and unused anyway.