# C minishell does not return immediately after I handle SIGINT

Tags: c, signals, sigint

I am trying to write a minishell with very limited built-in functionality. However, right now whenever I handle SIGINT, I have to hit enter again before being able to enter any more commands.

```
void loop()
{
    struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_handler = do_nothing;
    int exit_status;
    do
    {
        char **args;
        sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL);
        my_str("\nMINISHELL: ");
        my_str(current_directory);
        my_str("/ $: ");
        args = get_args();
        exit_status = execute(args);
    }
    while(exit_status);
}
void do_nothing()
{
    my_str("\nMINISHELL: ");
    my_str(current_directory);
    my_str("/ $: ");
}
```

I'm only allowed to use `<unistd.h>`, `<sys/types.h>`, `<signal.h>`, `<unistd.h>`, and `<sys/wait.h>`, as well as any methods that I write. i.e. `my_str()` is just a string print statement that I implemented with the `write()` sys call.

PLEASE HELP.

Comment: "_I'm only allowed to use , , , , and ,_"

What?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573842/use-of-sigaction

Comment: @jwdonahue OP had filenames with angle brackets, which the markdown engine treated as (unknown) HTML element tags. I fixed them so they're visible.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, oh of course!  I have only recently got serious about frequenting this site.  Still getting used to the interface.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are failing to initialize the entire `sigaction struct` and you are also calling I/O functions from within the handler. See [pubs.opengroup.org](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sigaction.html) for documentation and an example of setting up a SIGINT handler. Your handler shouldn't do very much.  Just set or increment a flag that your program's main loop can respond to.  You should also be checking the return status from the `sigaction` call.

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped a lot. Now my only problem is that if run minishell and hit ctrl+c before entering any other commands, it requires that I hit enter before entering other commands. However, in all other instances, it works fine. Thank you again.

Comment: Try doing an fflush(stdin) after you've detected the ctrl+c, just don't do it in the signal handler.